# How can I make a simple requestAnimationFrame loop in Rust with arguments?

Tags: rust, webassembly, requestanimationframe, wasm-bindgen

I am trying to make a requestAnimationFrame loop in Rust with arguments.

I've looked and found how to make a requestAnimationFrame loop like so:

```rust
fn loop() {
    // do stuff here

    let closure = Closure::wrap(Box::new(move || {
        loop();
    }) as Box<dyn FnMut()>);
    
    web_sys::window().unwrap().request_animation_frame(closure.as_ref().unchecked_ref()).unwrap();
    closure.forget();
}
```

However, I need to pass arguments to the `loop` function. In JavaScript it would look something like this:

```js
function loop(arg) {
    // do stuff with arg
    
    requestAnimationFrame(arg);
}
```

If I try adding an argument to the Rust function I get this error:

```
expected a closure that implements the `FnMut` trait, but this closure only implements `FnOnce`
required for the cast from `Box<{closure@src/main.rs:75:42: 75:49}>` to `Box<dyn FnMut()>
```

I can't use FnOnce because it doesn't implement the WasmClosure trait.

Comment: Looks like you're consuming the variable you closed over during the execution of the closure, so it can only run once, hence being an FnOnce (the item doesn't exist anymore the second time around). Without actually actionable anything, that's about as far as this can go I'd think.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e3f4c462a178af3edff3756da8341e8c)

Comment: You can make `Closure` of `FnOnce` by calling [`Closure::once_into_js()`](https://docs.rs/wasm-bindgen/latest/wasm_bindgen/closure/struct.Closure.html#method.once_into_js), although I haven't completely understood your question so I can't tell if this is the best solution.